# System.Data.Sqlite.EF связь между таблицами Many to Many

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Я разбираюсь как с помощью EF6 из System.Data.Sqlite создать связь между таблицами Many to Many, но у меня не получается прочитать данные, однако запись проходит верно. Так как System.Data.Sqlite.EF не умеет создавать базе, то я создал ее вручную, ниже код создания базы:

```
    PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

    CREATE TABLE "Cources" (
        "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
        "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE "Students" (
        "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
        "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
        "Age"   INTEGER
    );

    CREATE TABLE "StudentsCources" (
        "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
        "StudentID" INTEGER,
        "CourceID"  INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY("CourceID") REFERENCES "Cources"("ID"),
        FOREIGN KEY("StudentID") REFERENCES "Students"("ID")
    );
```

Модель и контекст базы тоже стандартна:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using Univerciry.Model;

    namespace Univerciry
    {        
            class Cource
            {
                public Cource()
                {
                    Students = new HashSet<Student>();
                }
                public int ID { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
            }
            class Student
            {
                public Student()
                {
                    Cources = new HashSet<Cource>();
                }
                public int ID { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public int Age { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<Cource> Cources { get; set;}
            }

            class UnivercityContext : DbContext
            {
                public DbSet<Cource> Cources { get; set; }
                public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

                protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
                {
                    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasMany(x => x.Cources).WithMany(x => x.Students).Map(x=> 
                    {
                        x.ToTable("StudentsCources");
                        x.MapLeftKey("StudentID");
                        x.MapRightKey("CourceID");
                     });
                     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                 }
             }
    }
```

Для вставки данных я использовал следующую конструкцию:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (UnivercityContext db = new UnivercityContext())
        {
            Student s_1 = new Student
            {
                Name = "Andrey",
                Age = 27
            };
            Student s_2 = new Student
            {
                Name = "Alex",
                Age = 0
            };
            List<Student> s = new List<Student> { s_1, s_2 };

            Cource cource_1 = new Cource
            {
                Name = "Math",
                Students = s
            };

            Cource cource_2 = new Cource
            {
                Name = "Programming",
                Students = s
            };

            List<Cource> c = new List<Cource> { cource_1, cource_2 };
            s_1.Cources = c;
            s_2.Cources = c;

            db.Students.Add(s_1);
            db.Students.Add(s_2);
            db.Cources.Add(cource_1);
            db.Cources.Add(cource_2);

            db.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```

На данном жтапе проблемм не каких нет. Данные созраняются и добавляются во все 3 таблицы. Теперь то что меня смущает:

При попытки чтения - база читается, однако не коллекции курсов и студентов остаются пустыми.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (UnivercityContext db = new UnivercityContext())
        {

            List<Student> student = db.Students.ToList();
            foreach (var item in student)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} has Age = {item.Age} Subscribed on following cources:");
                foreach (var c in item.Cources.ToList())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
                }
            }
            List<Cource> cources = db.Cources.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Подскажите где я  делаю ошибку ?

Я ожидаю увидеть:

> Andrey has Age = 27 Subscribed on following cources:
>
> Math
>
> Programming
>
> Alex has Age = 0 Subscribed on following cources:
>
> Math
>
> Programming

Но вместо этого вижу:

> Andrey has Age = 27 Subscribed on following cources:
>
> Alex has Age = 0 Subscribed on following cources:

---

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="UnivercityContext" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestUnivercityDB.db;Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Насколько я помню для ленивой выгрузки класс должен быть public, может проблема в этом.

Comment: @АлексейПотапов Вы правы, решение было элементарным оказывается.